# Check timing validation with scope in laravel

Tags: laravel, scope

I store 2 dates in my products table `start_discounted` and `end_discounted` this 2 columns are responsible of my discount price duration. Now when my product discount duration expires except it return back to normal price it stays on discounted price and my timer goes to minus.

[image: screen 1]

[image: screen 2]

## Codes

my model scope

```
public function scopeValidDiscount($query){
       return $query->where('start_discounted', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
                    ->where('end_discounted', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
    }
```

`controller`

```
public function product($slug){
     $product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
     $validdiscount = $product->ValidDiscount()->get();
     //...
}
```

`blade`

```
@if($validdiscount)
  show timer
@endif
```

> **PS:** I need to avoid showing timer in 2 conditions, `1` discount dates are expired. `2` Product discount dates are null.

Any idea where is my mistake?

## UPDATE

My timer in blade:

```
@if($validdiscount)
<div class="deals_timer row align-items-center">
<div class="col-md-6 deals_timer_title_container">
<div class="deals_timer_title">{{__('store.hurryup')}}</div>
<div class="deals_timer_subtitle">{{__('store.endsin')}}</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 deals_timer_content ml-auto">
<div class="deals_timer_box clearfix" data-target-time="{{$end}}">
<div class="text-center deals_timer_unit">
<div id="deals_timer3_hr" class="deals_timer_hr"></div>
<span>{{__('store.hours')}}</span>
</div>
<div class="text-center deals_timer_unit">
<div id="deals_timer3_min" class="deals_timer_min"></div>
<span>{{__('store.mins')}}</span>
</div>
<div class="text-center deals_timer_unit">
<div id="deals_timer3_sec" class="deals_timer_sec"></div>
<span>{{__('store.secs')}}</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
@endif
```

Please pay attention to `data-target-time="{{$end}}"` i think the issue might be here...

my timer script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($('.deals_timer_box').length)
        {
            var timers = $('.deals_timer_box');
            timers.each(function()
            {
                var timer = $(this);

                var targetTime;
                var target_date;

                // Add a date to data-target-time of the .deals_timer_box
                // Format: "Feb 17, 2018"
                if(timer.data('target-time') !== "")
                {
                    targetTime = timer.data('target-time');
                    target_date = new Date(targetTime).getTime();
                }
                else
                {
                    var date = new Date();
                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2);
                    target_date = date.getTime();
                }

                // variables for time units
                var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

                var h = timer.find('.deals_timer_hr');
                var m = timer.find('.deals_timer_min');
                var s = timer.find('.deals_timer_sec');

                setInterval(function ()
                {
                    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
                    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
                    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
                    console.log(seconds_left);

                    // do some time calculations
                    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
                    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

                    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
                    hours = hours + days * 24;
                    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;


                    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
                    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

                    if(hours.toString().length < 2)
                    {
                        hours = "0" + hours;
                    }
                    if(minutes.toString().length < 2)
                    {
                        minutes = "0" + minutes;
                    }
                    if(seconds.toString().length < 2)
                    {
                        seconds = "0" + seconds;
                    }

                    // display results
                    h.text(hours);
                    m.text(minutes);
                    s.text(seconds); 

                }, 1000);
            }); 
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

#### {{$end}}

This is what I have in my controller in order to get my expired date and use if in my JavaScript above:

```
$mytime = Carbon::now();
if(!empty($product->start_discounted && $product->end_discounted)){
  $start = $product->start_discounted->format('M d, Y');
  $end = $product->end_discounted->format('M d, Y');
}
```

then I also have my scope code:

```
$validdiscount = $product->ValidDiscount()->get();
```

> now what I think is that my issue cause by: I get my expire date from
>   product directly `$product->end_discounted` while I try to avoid it while I'm using scope which
>   it does the same carbon thing in my model, not sure! (maybe i should get my `$end` by scope as well?

Comment: any details on the `show timer` part? i believe its view related.

Comment: I'm more interested in why you're calling a scope (`validDiscount()`) on an already fetched `Product`. Are `start_discounted` and `end_discounted` fields on the product table?

Comment: @BagusTesa Updated my question.

Comment: @devk yes they are as i explained at the top of my question, `I store 2 dates in my products table` so I'm not using any discount table that's why my scope is in my products table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using scopes correctly. [Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes) are used on query builder, not on an already retrieved model.

For doing this, you just need a regular method:

```
public function validDiscount() {
    return $this->start_discounted <= now()->toDateTimeString()
        && $this->end_discounted >= now()->toDateTimeString();
}
```

And then in your view, check it like this:

```
@if($product->validDiscount())
  show timer
@endif
```

And remove the unneeded `$validdiscount = $product->ValidDiscount()->get();` (where you're using a query scope on an instance of a model).

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript/jquery in front end to do it.

1. When you populate that page, call that js function to check that value like this `$(document).ready(function(){ check_timer() })`
2. Then trigger that method again when you timer has expired to update your view(hide promotional price, hide timer & showing actual price)

check_timer function can be like this

```
function check_timer(){
  if(!{{ $validdiscount }}){
   //hide your required div 
 }
}
```

Comment: I am using JavaScript for my timer. I will update my question.